# Make 2 UIScrollViews zoom and scroll identically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a screen which has two UIScrollViews.  Inside the scrollview is a zoomable UIImageView.

I'd like to achieve the same scrolling and zooming inside one scrollView to be applied to the other one.  i.e. if the user pans across the image, both scrollviews pan their images at the exact same rate.  If the user pinch zooms the image in one, the other zooms exactly the same amount.

I've read on here about using the zoomToRect:animated: call.  I'm not sure exactly how to implement that, so I've tried the following - but it doesn't seem to yield the right results.  NB. the scrollView contain self.imageViewLeft.  self.scrollViewRight is the scrollView not being touched.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect visibleRect = [scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds toView:self.imageViewLeft];
    [self.scrollViewRight zoomToRect:visibleRect animated:false];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it guys!  Props to me.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (scrollView == self.scrollViewLeft) {
        [self.scrollViewRight setZoomScale:[scrollView zoomScale]];
        [self.scrollViewRight setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset]];
    } else {
        [self.scrollViewLeft setZoomScale:[scrollView zoomScale]];
        [self.scrollViewLeft setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset]];
    }
}
```